# DataGridView TextBox Cell Validating in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, addition, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have two DataGridViewTextbox Column in my Form. I want to compare one textbox with another textbox value.

See the image the information is provided there...,

which are in blue color they are readonly ......I tried and i get the answer

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Boss i don't get any Idea..., i am thinking

Comment: So what do you need to compare? Do you need to compare Quantity Required vs Quantity Issues??

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["Quantity"].Value > DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["other"].Value)
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amir i am not asking the cell value.the sum of Quantity issued is not greater than the value of the consumable required

Answer (score 0):

Attach your grid to `CellValidating` event:

```
private void GridCellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == ColQuantityIssues.Index)  // Quantity Issues TextBox value has changed
    {
        int quantityIssued = 0;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out quantityRequired))  //value is not a valid number
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }

        int quantityRequired = Int32.Parse(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[ColQuantityRequired.Index].Value.ToString());

        if (quantityRequired < quantityIssued)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Event args has `FormattedValue` which is the new value user has entered. Setting `e.Cancel` to true won't allow user to leave current cell as long as value is not valid one.

You may change my ColQuantityIssues and ColQuantityRequired to access them by name (i.e. dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Required"]) but that should work.